# Plot multiple paths from a dataframe using Folium (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, folium

I'm new to folium and I can't figure out how I could plot multiple folium routes while iterating over dataframe groups.
Here is my dataframe :

```
df
     Group   Lat    Long
0      a     ...     ...
1      a     ...     ...
2      a     ...     ...
3      b     ...     ...
4      b     ...     ...
```

What I'd like is to get 2 paths displayed on the folium map. The first one between all the 'a group' markers and the second one between all the 'b group' markers.
Thank you for your help!